# Facebook Canvas IE 9 iFrame security issue

Tags: internet-explorer-9, facebook-canvas

Occasionally, I will notice that IE9 will not display my application, it will display this message:

"To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."

It only occurs sporadically, if I refresh the whole canvas window it usually just goes away. 
Any ideas on why this could be occuring?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That *normally* happens (and is supposed to) when the web server sends an `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header with a value of `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN` – but if you’re not doing that for your app, then it would have to be something else. Or are you doing that somewhere else on your site, and under certain conditions this might happen for your app pages as well?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not messing with X-Frame-Options. From what I've read it can only be DENY or SAMEORIGIN; it's too bad there's not some setting like ALLOW.